# How to avoid adding new records in df.loc[row,col]=val? (when updating DataFrame value)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to update its value based on index.

In my case, I have a data file too large to read into memory, so I just read it line by line. Here I just take a dictionary as an example, which maps from df index to a value.

The problem is in the code bellow, a new row will be added to the df after the for loop.

I came across a solution, adding condition `if key in df.index:`, but the time complexity seems too high and I'm not sure if there's a better solution for large dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df  # only 3 rows
Out[20]: 
  alpha
0     a
1     b
2     c

trans = {1: 'B',2: 'C',3: 'D'}
for key, val in trans.items():
    df.loc[key, 'alpha'] = val
    
df  # change to 4 rows
Out[23]: 
  alpha
0     a
1     B
2     C
3     D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df
###
  alpha
0     a
1     b
2     c
```

Actually we wanna use `replace()` to get the job done.
`replace()` within dict having corresponding mapped values.

```
trans_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'target': trans.values()}, 
    index=trans.keys())
trans_df
###
  target
1      B
2      C
3      D
```

```
map_target = dict(df.join(trans_df).dropna().values)
map_target
###
{'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'} ← This is what we need
```

```
df['alpha'] = df['alpha'].replace(map_target)
df
###
  alpha
0     a
1     B
2     C
```